# Django form error:local variable 'context' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x

I'm collecting data from form, processing data(right now I'm not) and displaying the result on the same HTML page from where the user submits the form.

Here is my views.py file:

```
def index(request):
    template = 'predictor/index.html'

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = EvalForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text ='thank you for submitting form'
        else:
            text='something wrong.'

        context: {
            'text':text,
            }   
        return render(request,template,context)


    else:
        form = EvalForm()
        return render(request,template)
```

Here is my index.html file

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'predictor' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}

//all input fields including submit button here

</form>
<div class="result">
            {{ text }}
</div>
```

All other things like urls are configured properly.
What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please correct your indentation and post your error traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in your code.
Should be `context = {'text':text,}` instead of `context: {'text':text,}`.

Comment: holy crap!! I didn't notice that. Thank you for pointing out the silly mistake. Now it's working fine. Should I delete the question? I feel so dumb right now. -_-

Comment: @Scorpionk don't worry we all make mistakes:)

Comment: OK. Does my code look messy? I mean Is this the best approach if we want to print the result of submitted form on the same page? I'm kinda new to Django.

Comment: @Scorpionk it looks fine. One small advice you dont need else block if you are using `form = EvalForm(request.POST or None)` hack. Check example here: https://gist.github.com/pylemon/2330177

Comment: @Scorpionk oh and one more thing. To display messages on the web page you can use dango messages: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/